# Printing a plot in Octave-3.8.1 breaks LaTeX labels

Tags: visualization, octave

Since upgrading to Octave 3.8 I have been unable to export plots with LaTeX labels. When the figure is displayed the labels render fine but when I try to export the figure using the `print` command the labels come out as a raw string.

For example:

```
x = 0:0.01:(2*pi);
y = sin(x.^2 + cos(x)).^3;
plot(x,y)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('sin^3(x^2 + cos(x))')
print('test1.png')
```

produces,

[image: screenshot of figure.]

and saves,

[image: exported figure with mangled labels]

Does anyone know how to fix this or hack around it?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Questions about (suspected) bugs in specific software packages are [off-topic](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site; you should try the [Octave mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-octave).

Comment: This sounds like a great question to ask on the Octve user mailing list (help@octave.org, I think).

Comment: Agreed; this post should go to the Octave mailing list.

Comment: Sorry for asking an off topic question!

If anyone finds this needing a solution I did actually get a response from the Octave maintainers (http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42988).